# Implementing STARTTLS in a protocol in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, starttls

I'm trying to add a STARTTLS upgrade to an existing protocol (which currently works in plaintext).

As a start, I'm using a simple line-based echoing server (it's a horrible kludge with no error handling or processing of packets into lines - but it usually just works as the console sends a line-at-a-time to stdin).

I think my server is right, but both ends exit with identical errors when I type `starttls`:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: 139652888721216:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766:

    at SlabBuffer.use (tls.js:232:18)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:450:29)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:221:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:211:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
```

Have I completely misunderstood how to do an upgrade on the client side?

Currently, I'm using the same method to add TLS-ness to plain streams at each end.  This feels wrong, as both client and server will be trying to play the same role in the negotiation.

tlsserver.js:

```
r tls = require('tls');
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),

  // This is necessary only if using the client certificate authentication.
  requestCert: true,

  // This is necessary only if the client uses the self-signed certificate.
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem') ],

  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('plain data: ', data);
    // FIXME: this is not robust, it should be processing the stream into lines
    if (data.substr(0, 8) === 'starttls') {
      console.log('server starting TLS');
      //socket.write('server starting TLS');
      socket.removeAllListeners('data');

      options.socket = socket;
      sec_socket = tls.connect(options, (function() {
        sec_socket.on('data', function() {
          console.log('secure data: ', data);
        });
        return callback(null, true);
      }).bind(this));
    } else {
      console.log('plain data', data);
    }
  });
});

server.listen(9999, function() {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

client.js:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');

var options = {
  // These are necessary only if using the client certificate authentication
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),

  // This is necessary only if the server uses the self-signed certificate
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ],
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};


var socket = new net.Socket();
var sec_socket = undefined;

socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('plain data:', data);
});
socket.connect(9999, function() {
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
  process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    if (!sec_socket) {
      console.log('sending plain:', data);
      socket.write(data);
    } else {
      console.log('sending secure:', data);
      sec_socket.write(data);
    }
    if (data.substr(0, 8) === 'starttls') {
      console.log('client starting tls');
      socket.removeAllListeners('data');
      options.socket = socket;
      sec_socket = tls.connect(options, (function() {
        sec_socket.on('data', function() {
          console.log('secure data: ', data);
        });
        return callback(null, true);
      }).bind(this));
    }
  });
});
```

---

Got it working, thanks to Matt Seargeant's answer.  My code now looks like:

server.js:

```
var ts = require('./tls_socket');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),

  // This is necessary only if using the client certificate authentication.
  requestCert: false,

  // This is necessary only if the client uses the self-signed certificate.
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem') ],

  rejectUnauthorized: false
};



var server = ts.createServer(function(socket) {
  console.log('connected');
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data', data);
    if (data.length === 9) {
      console.log('upgrading to TLS');
      socket.upgrade(options, function() {
        console.log('upgraded to TLS');
      });
    }
  });
});
server.listen(9999);
```

client.js:

```
var ts = require('./tls_socket');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var options = {
  // These are necessary only if using the client certificate authentication
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),

  // This is necessary only if the server uses the self-signed certificate
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ],

  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var socket = ts.connect(9999, 'localhost', function() {
  console.log('secured');
});

process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('sending:', data);
  socket.write(data);
  if (data.length === 9) {
    socket.upgrade(options);
  }
});
```

tls_socket.js:

```
"use strict";
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Obtained and modified from http://js.5sh.net/starttls.js on 8/18/2011.                       */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var tls = require('tls');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var util = require('util');
var net = require('net');
var stream = require('stream');
var SSL_OP_ALL = require('constants').SSL_OP_ALL;

// provides a common socket for attaching
// and detaching from either main socket, or crypto socket
function pluggableStream(socket) {
    stream.Stream.call(this);
    this.readable = this.writable = true;
    this._timeout = 0;
    this._keepalive = false;
    this._writeState = true;
    this._pending = [];
    this._pendingCallbacks = [];
    if (socket)
        this.attach(socket);
}

util.inherits(pluggableStream, stream.Stream);

pluggableStream.prototype.pause = function () {
    if (this.targetsocket.pause) {
        this.targetsocket.pause();
        this.readable = false;
    }
}

pluggableStream.prototype.resume = function () {
    if (this.targetsocket.resume) {
        this.readable = true;
        this.targetsocket.resume();
    }
}

pluggableStream.prototype.attach = function (socket) {
    var self = this;
    self.targetsocket = socket;
    self.targetsocket.on('data', function (data) {
        self.emit('data', data);
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('connect', function (a, b) {
        self.emit('connect', a, b);
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('secureConnection', function (a, b) {
        self.emit('secureConnection', a, b);
        self.emit('secure', a, b);
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('secure', function (a, b) {
        self.emit('secureConnection', a, b);
        self.emit('secure', a, b);
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('end', function () {
        self.writable = self.targetsocket.writable;
        self.emit('end');
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('close', function (had_error) {
        self.writable = self.targetsocket.writable;
        self.emit('close', had_error);
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('drain', function () {
        self.emit('drain');
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('error', function (exception) {
        self.writable = self.targetsocket.writable;
        self.emit('error', exception);
    });
    self.targetsocket.on('timeout', function () {
        self.emit('timeout');
    });
    if (self.targetsocket.remotePort) {
        self.remotePort = self.targetsocket.remotePort;
    }
    if (self.targetsocket.remoteAddress) {
        self.remoteAddress = self.targetsocket.remoteAddress;
    }
};

pluggableStream.prototype.clean = function (data) {
    if (this.targetsocket && this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners) {
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('data');
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('secureConnection');
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('secure');
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('end');
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('close');
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('error');
        this.targetsocket.removeAllListeners('drain');
    }
    this.targetsocket = {};
    this.targetsocket.write = function () {};
};

pluggableStream.prototype.write = function (data, encoding, callback) {
    if (this.targetsocket.write) {
        return this.targetsocket.write(data, encoding, callback);
    }
    return false;
};

pluggableStream.prototype.end = function (data, encoding) {
    if (this.targetsocket.end) {
        return this.targetsocket.end(data, encoding);
    }
}

pluggableStream.prototype.destroySoon = function () {
    if (this.targetsocket.destroySoon) {
        return this.targetsocket.destroySoon();
    }
}

pluggableStream.prototype.destroy = function () {
    if (this.targetsocket.destroy) {
        return this.targetsocket.destroy();
    }
}

pluggableStream.prototype.setKeepAlive = function (bool) {
    this._keepalive = bool;
    return this.targetsocket.setKeepAlive(bool);
};

pluggableStream.prototype.setNoDelay = function (/* true||false */) {
};

pluggableStream.prototype.setTimeout = function (timeout) {
    this._timeout = timeout;
    return this.targetsocket.setTimeout(timeout);
};

function pipe(pair, socket) {
    pair.encrypted.pipe(socket);
    socket.pipe(pair.encrypted);

    pair.fd = socket.fd;
    var cleartext = pair.cleartext;
    cleartext.socket = socket;
    cleartext.encrypted = pair.encrypted;
    cleartext.authorized = false;

    function onerror(e) {
        if (cleartext._controlReleased) {
            cleartext.emit('error', e);
        }
    }

    function onclose() {
        socket.removeListener('error', onerror);
        socket.removeListener('close', onclose);
    }

    socket.on('error', onerror);
    socket.on('close', onclose);

    return cleartext;
}

function createServer(cb) {
    var serv = net.createServer(function (cryptoSocket) {

        var socket = new pluggableStream(cryptoSocket);

        socket.upgrade = function (options, cb) {
            console.log("Upgrading to TLS");

            socket.clean();
            cryptoSocket.removeAllListeners('data');

            // Set SSL_OP_ALL for maximum compatibility with broken clients
            // See http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html
            if (!options) options = {};
            // TODO: bug in Node means we can't do this until it's fixed
            // options.secureOptions = SSL_OP_ALL;

            var sslcontext = crypto.createCredentials(options);

            var pair = tls.createSecurePair(sslcontext, true, true, false);

            var cleartext = pipe(pair, cryptoSocket);

            pair.on('error', function(exception) {
                socket.emit('error', exception);
            });

            pair.on('secure', function() {
                var verifyError = (pair.ssl || pair._ssl).verifyError();

                console.log("TLS secured.");
                if (verifyError) {
                    cleartext.authorized = false;
                    cleartext.authorizationError = verifyError;
                } else {
                    cleartext.authorized = true;
                }
                var cert = pair.cleartext.getPeerCertificate();
                if (pair.cleartext.getCipher) {
                    var cipher = pair.cleartext.getCipher();
                }
                socket.emit('secure');
                if (cb) cb(cleartext.authorized, verifyError, cert, cipher);
            });

            cleartext._controlReleased = true;

            socket.cleartext = cleartext;

            if (socket._timeout) {
                cleartext.setTimeout(socket._timeout);
            }

            cleartext.setKeepAlive(socket._keepalive);

            socket.attach(socket.cleartext);
        };

        cb(socket);
    });

    return serv;
}

if (require('semver').gt(process.version, '0.7.0')) {
    var _net_connect = function (options) {
        return net.connect(options);
    }
}
else {
    var _net_connect = function (options) {
        return net.connect(options.port, options.host);
    }
}

function connect(port, host, cb) {
    var options = {};
    if (typeof port === 'object') {
        options = port;
        cb = host;
    }
    else {
        options.port = port;
        options.host = host;
    }

    var cryptoSocket = _net_connect(options);

    var socket = new pluggableStream(cryptoSocket);

    socket.upgrade = function (options) {
        socket.clean();
        cryptoSocket.removeAllListeners('data');

        // Set SSL_OP_ALL for maximum compatibility with broken servers
        // See http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html
        if (!options) options = {};
        // TODO: bug in Node means we can't do this until it's fixed
        // options.secureOptions = SSL_OP_ALL;

        var sslcontext = crypto.createCredentials(options);

        var pair = tls.createSecurePair(sslcontext, false);

        socket.pair = pair;

        var cleartext = pipe(pair, cryptoSocket);

        pair.on('error', function(exception) {
            socket.emit('error', exception);
        });

        pair.on('secure', function() {
            var verifyError = (pair.ssl || pair._ssl).verifyError();

            console.log("client TLS secured.");
            if (verifyError) {
                cleartext.authorized = false;
                cleartext.authorizationError = verifyError;
            } else {
                cleartext.authorized = true;
            }

            if (cb) cb();

            socket.emit('secure');
        });

        cleartext._controlReleased = true;
        socket.cleartext = cleartext;

        if (socket._timeout) {
            cleartext.setTimeout(socket._timeout);
        }

        cleartext.setKeepAlive(socket._keepalive);

        socket.attach(socket.cleartext);

        console.log("client TLS upgrade in progress, awaiting secured.");
    };

    return (socket);
}

exports.connect = connect;
exports.createConnection = connect;
exports.Server = createServer;
exports.createServer = createServer;
```

Comment: Perhaps I should be using SecurePair http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurepair_credentials_isserver_requestcert_rejectunauthorized rather than `tls.connect` at the client, or at both ends.  I'll test after lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tls.connect() doesn't support the server doing the upgrade unfortunately.

You have to use code similar to how Haraka does it - basically creating your own shim using a SecurePair.

See here for the code we use: https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka/blob/master/tls_socket.js#L171

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that both the client and server code need to upgrade?  And that the request is communicated in the plaintext aplication protocol?

Comment: I hacked your tls_socket.js file so that it didn't need the rest of Haraka and it ran first time!  I'll paste my code into the original question, in case anyone else has trouble with TLS.

Answer (score 1):

STARTTLS Client-Server is trivial to implement in node, but it be a [little buggy](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10555) so, we need to go around.

For Server of STARTTLS we need do it:

```js
// sock come from: net.createServer(function(sock) { ... });            
sock.removeAllListeners('data');
sock.removeAllListeners('error');

sock.write('220 Go ahead' + CRLF); 
sock = new tls.TLSSocket(sock, { secureContext : tls.createSecureContext({ key: cfg.stls.key, cert: cfg.stls.cert }), rejectUnauthorized: false, isServer: true });
sock.setEncoding('utf8');  

// 'secureConnect' event is buggy :/ we need to use 'secure' here.
sock.on('secure', function() {
  // STARTTLS is done here. sock is a secure socket in server side.
  sock.on('error', parseError);
  sock.on('data', parseData); 
});
```

For Client of STARTTLS we need do it:

```js
// sock come from: net.connect(cfg.port, curr.exchange);
// here we already read the '220 Go ahead' from the server.
sock.removeAllListeners('data');
sock.removeAllListeners('error');

sock = tls.connect({ socket: sock, secureContext : tls.createSecureContext({ key: cfg.stls.key, cert: cfg.stls.cert }), rejectUnauthorized: false });

sock.on('secureConnect', function() {
  // STARTTLS is done here. sock is a secure socket in client side.
  sock.on('error', parseError);
  sock.on('data', parseData); 
  // Resend the helo message.
  sock.write(helo); 
});
```